# Javascript require Method within another require method

Tags: javascript, require

(Someone may change the title accordingly)
What happens exactly when javascript's `require` method is called like this:

```
var xyz = require('xy')(require('z'));
```

thank you

Comment: For your code you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: @MohamedAbbas: actually I don't
`var gulp = require('gulp-help')(require('gulp'));` I have this fully working

Comment: Sorry i was wrong, i didn't read the code well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var gulp = require('gulp-help')(require('gulp'));` works because `require('gulp-help')` returns you a function and then that takes the module exported by gulp as an argument, along with the options

like

```
require('gulp-help')(require('gulp'), options);

These are all the options available to be passed to the gulp-help instance, NOT individual tasks.

description - modifies the default help message
aliases - adds aliases to the default help task
hideEmpty - hide all tasks with no help message defined. Useful when including 3rd party tasks
hideDepsMessage - hide all task dependencies
afterPrintCallback - a function to run after the default help task runs
```

This is a short form for

```
var gulp-help = require('gulp-help');
var gulp = gulp-help(require('gulp'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the `z` module exports will be passed in as an argument to the function that is being exported from `xy`.

If `xy` doesn't export a function, then you would get an error

Answer (score 1):

It's short for this:

```
var xy  = require('xy');
var z   = require('z');
var xyz = xy(z);
```